# Two questions related to characteristic functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a random vector such that:
$$\varphi_X(t)=\exp\{\lambda (\varphi_\mu(t) -1 )\}$$
This means that $X = \sum_{j=1}^N W_j$, where $N \sim \hbox{Poisson}(\lambda)$, $(W_j)\overset{iid}{\sim}\mu$ and $(W_j)\perp N$ (This is the random vector with Compound Poisson distribution). Denote this as $X\sim CP(\lambda, \mu)$.

Now consider $X_1\sim CP(\lambda_1, \mu_1)$ and $X_2\sim CP(\lambda_2, \mu_2)$ independent.
First, consider these two questions:

- Find the characteristic function of $X=X_1+X_2$;
- Show that $X$ has a Compound Poisson distribution compounding a [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution).

I can deal with the first:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\varphi_X (t) &= \prod_{i = 1}^2 \varphi_{X_i}(t) =  \prod_{i = 1}^2 \exp\left\{ \lambda_i ( \varphi_{\mu_i} (t) - 1) \right\} = \exp\left\{ \sum_{i = 1}^2 \lambda_i \left( \int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{iu^\intercal x} d\mu_i(x) - 1\right)\right\}\\
&= \exp\left\{ \sum_{i = 1}^2  \int_{\mathbb  R^n} \left( e^{iu^\intercal x} -1 \right) \lambda_id\mu_i(x) \right\} = \exp\left\{  \int_{\mathbb R^n} \left( e^{iu^\intercal x} -1 \right) d\mu(x) \right\}     
\end{aligned}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $\mu = \lambda_1 \mu_1 + \lambda_2 \mu_2$ is a measure. (Note that $\mu$ is not a probability measures like $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are). At first, I thought that Equation (1) would involve the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Convolution_of_measures) $\mu_1*\mu_2$. So I have 2 questions:

**Questions**

1. Note that $\mu_i(\mathbb R^n)=1$. Denoting $\lambda:= \mu(\mathbb R^n) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 $, define $ \nu (E):= \frac{\mu(E)}{\lambda}$. Can we say that $\nu = \mu_1 * \mu_2$?
2. Since $\nu$ is a measure. I can rewritte (1) as:
   \begin{equation}
   \varphi_X(t)= \exp\left\{ \lambda  \int_{\mathbb R^n} \left( e^{iu^\intercal x} -1 \right) d\nu(x) \right\},
   \end{equation}
   i.e. $X \sim CP(\lambda, \nu)$. But I have no idea how $\nu$ could be a mixture of measures. How to do this?

I appreciate any help on these two questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping $\lambda=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ and introduce the mixed probability

$$\nu=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda}\mu_1+\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda}\mu_2$$

Comment: Thanks, Gerard.  And regarding the first question.  Is $\nu$ the convolution of $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$?

Comment: Of course not in general.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you don't mind, I'd like to clear up one more thing. I understand that $\mu = \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda} \mu_1 + \frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda} \mu_2 $ is a mixture, but what about $\nu= \frac{\mu}{\lambda}$, as defined in my previous question? It also define a valid compound Poisson distribution. In other words, does $X=X_1 + X_2$ have two different meanings? I'm still a bit confused about the distinction between these two versions.

Answer (score 1):

Several meanings of $\mu$ are very confusing.  Let me write $ p=\lambda_1/\lambda$ and $q=1-p=\lambda_2/\lambda$ for simplicity.  Recall that $\mu_1$,$ \mu_2$ and $\nu=p\mu_1+q\mu_2$ are probabilities.  If $\Pr(U=0)=q$ and $\Pr(U=1)=p$ and if $U, W_1\sim \mu_1,\ W_2\sim \mu_2$ are independent then $W=UW_1+(1-U)W_2\sim \nu.$ Finally if $X_1\sim CP(\lambda_1,\mu_1)$ and $X_2\sim CP(\lambda_2,\mu_2)$ then $X=X_1+X_2 \sim CP(\lambda_1+\lambda_2,\nu).$

Comment: Dear, thank you. Very interesting to have these two valid interpretations with the same distribution.